# Python manage.py permission denied in Windows

Tags: windows-10, python, django

I created a Python project and then tried to run the command `python manage.py runserver` in VS Code terminal but it keeps on displaying permission denied.

[image: Python permission denied]

Comment: That error means the console can't access the python interpreter. Are you sure it's in that location? Is the path to the interpreter in the `PATH` variable? Is the interpreter available to your user?